# Фильтр потока данных по данным из другого потока

Tags: android, rxjava

Есть такой объект

```
class SomeObject {
    int id;
    String name;
    /*на самом деле объект более сложный
    есть другие поля, методы*/
  }
```

Имеются поток с этими объектами `Observable<SomeObject> someObjectObservable` и поток с отфильтрованными по определенному критерию идентификаторами `Observable<Integer> idObservable`.

Так вот, необходимо отфильтровать поток `someObjectObservable`, исходя из потока идентификаторов `idObservable`, в результате чего нужно получить новый поток отфильтрованных объектов `Observable<SomeObject>`

Сейчас реализовано так:

```
idObservable
  .map(id -> someObjectObservable.filter(someObject -> someObject.getId() == id).firstElment().blockingGet());
```

Вот, есть подозрение. что реализация не совсем оптимальная, хотя исходную задачу выполняет.

Есть ли другие способы решения задачи или текущая реализация нормальная?

Comment: Почему бы просто не изменять по мапе уже существующий поток и не делать дополнительные?

Comment: @Implozia, а можно поподробнее? Два потока идут с разных источников. Мапать поток с идентификаторами в полноценный объект `SomeObject` как-то накладно, думаю, выйдет. Так как объекты на самом деле достаточно тяжелые, с вложенной картинкой (да, возможно не совсем корректно был спроектирован класс, но что есть, то есть, возможно в будущем перепроектирую). Мапать же объекты `SomeObject` в поток идентификаторов, тоже не вижу смысла.

Comment: Тут возникла идея, может попробовать соединить два потока, преобразовав в `Pair<Integer, SomeObject>`, при этом из потока с идентификаторами получить `(id, null)`. Затем сгруппировать по идентификатору и проверять сгруппированные данные? Что-то сложно получается.

Comment: Похоже, я зря волнуюсь по поводу реализованного способа... Единственное, что можно улучшить, может даже было бы правильнее, так это `.map(id -> someObjectObservable.filter(someObject -> someObject.getId() == id).firstElment().blockingGet())` заменить на  `.flatMap(id -> someObjectObservable.filter(someObject -> someObject.getId() == id))`